# How to get the table names from a *.mdb file using java jdbc-odbc bridge?

Tags: java, database, jdbc-odbc

```
 String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + f.getPath() + ";";  
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = meta.getTables(conn.getCatalog(), null, "TAB_%", null);
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData=tables.getMetaData();
        int count=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             String str=rsMetaData.getTableName(i);
             System.out.println("table = " + str);
        }
```

The code above have some problem

```
   java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver programming manager] Invalid descriptor indexing(translate by myself from chinese)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLColAttributesString(JdbcOdbc.java:2674)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSetMetaData.getColAttributeString(JdbcOdbcResultSetMetaData.java:792)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSetMetaData.getTableName(JdbcOdbcResultSetMetaData.java:466)
```

I want to get the table names from a mdb file for execute sql query using jdbc-odbc bridge with the file path only, can someone help? Thks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are iterating through a table to collection from 0 to count, where count is the number of columns:

```
int count=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
```

That could give the error you're getting if there are more columns than tables.

Comment: Thanks you a lot! I debug and find the size of variable table in my code is 0. I think maybe there is a problem with the 3rd parameter in the function meta.getTables(), so I change "TAB_%" to "%" and it can get all the table names not only what I want but also system tables like 'MSysAccessObjects', 'MSysObjects' etc. How can I get the actual  table name?Thanks again.

Comment: A search for DatabaseMetaData.getTables returns some pages which might help.